$\int_0^{2\pi}\arccos\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right)dx$
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\arccos\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right)dx$$
I started by splitting it into multiple intervals
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\arccos\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right)dx=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\arccos\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right)dx+\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{2\pi}\arccos\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right)dx$$
which is
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\pi}{2}-xdx+\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{2\pi}\arccos\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right)dx$$
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\arccos\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right)dx=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\pi}{2}-xdx+\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{2\pi}\arccos\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right)dx$$
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\arccos\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right)dx=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\pi}{2}-xdx$\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}\pi-\arccos\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right)dx+\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}\arccos\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right)$+$$
and so on , would that be right?
Source :- MIT integration BEE

you should really draw a graph of $y = \arccos \sin x$

tell you what: what are $\arccos \sin \frac{\pi}{2} ; , ; ; ; \arccos \sin \frac{2\pi}{3} ; , ; ; ;  \arccos  \sin \frac{3\pi}{4} ; , ; ; ; \arccos \sin \frac{5\pi}{6} ; , ; ; ; \arccos \sin \pi ; ; ; ?  ; ; ; ; $

$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \arccos(\sin(x)) \, dx
$$
To solve this integral, we'll use the property $\arccos(\sin(x)) = \frac{\pi}{2} - \arcsin(\sin(x))$.
Now, let's break the integral into three parts:
$$
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \arcsin(\sin(x))\right) \, dx + \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}} \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \arcsin(\sin(x))\right) \, dx + \int_{\frac{3\pi}{2}}^{2\pi} \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \arcsin(\sin(x))\right) \, dx
$$
For $0 \leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, $\arcsin(\sin(x)) = x$, so the first integral becomes:
$$
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - x\right) \, dx = \left[\frac{\pi}{2}x - \frac{x^2}{2}\right]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} = \frac{\pi^2}{4} - \frac{\pi^2}{8} = \frac{\pi^2}{8}
$$
For $\frac{\pi}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{3\pi}{2}$, $\arcsin(\sin(x)) = \pi - x$, so the second integral becomes:
$$
\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}} \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - (\pi - x)\right) \, dx = \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}} (x - \frac{\pi}{2}) \, dx = \left[\frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{\pi}{2}x\right]_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}} = \frac{\pi^2}{2}
$$
For $\frac{3\pi}{2} \leq x \leq 2\pi$, $\arcsin(\sin(x)) = x - 2\pi$, so the third integral becomes:
$$
\int_{\frac{3\pi}{2}}^{2\pi} \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - (x - 2\pi)\right) \, dx = \int_{\frac{3\pi}{2}}^{2\pi} (2.5\pi - x) \, dx = \left[2.5\pi x - \frac{x^2}{2}\right]_{\frac{3\pi}{2}}^{2\pi} = \frac{3\pi^2}{8}
$$
Adding all three results:
$$
\frac{\pi^2}{8} + \frac{\pi^2}{2} + \frac{3\pi^2}{8} = \pi^2
$$
Therefore, the final result of the integral is $\pi^2$.
Hope it helps!
You can also do it very easily through drawing graph and calculating area of triangles, will be quite short as well.

thanks! Isn't the identity $arcsin(x)+arccos(x) =π/2$ only valid on $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}$ though?

Nope, it is always true whenever x lies in $[-1,1]$, the interval $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ is not of any real significance in inverse trignometric functions, or atleast in this case.

Recognize that $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ assume the same functional value over $(0,2\pi)$, albeit in mismatched subdomains
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\arccos\left(\sin x\right)dx=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\arccos\left(\cos x\right)dx\\
 =2\int_{0}^{\pi}\arccos\left(\cos x\right)dx= 2\int_{0}^{\pi}xdx=\pi^2
$$

By help of graph:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\arccos\left(\sin x\right)dx
=\int_{\frac\pi 2}^{\frac{5\pi}2}\arccos\left(\sin x\right)dx
=2\int_{\frac\pi 2}^{\frac{3\pi}2}\arccos\left(\sin x\right)dx
=2\int_{\frac\pi 2}^{\frac{3\pi}2}(x-\frac\pi 2)dx=\pi^2
$$

Just like @OpateItZOpatoOpate, we also use identity
$$\arccos x+\arcsin x=\frac\pi2,\quad x\in[-1,1],$$
then
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\arccos\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right){\rm d}x
=\pi^2-\int_0^{2\pi}\arcsin\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right){\rm d}x.$$
In the following, we give a easy method to computer the last integral:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\arcsin\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right){\rm d}x
=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\arcsin\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right){\rm d}x
=0,$$
here the first $=$ is due to $\arcsin(\sin(x+2\pi))=\arcsin(\sin x)$ and the second $=$ is due to $\arcsin(\sin(-x))=-\arcsin(\sin x)$.
Hence
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\arccos\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right){\rm d}x
=\pi^2.$$
